# Naming conventions for constants in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions

When a constant variable ends with a number, do you need to put an underscore in between the number and the rest of the variable?
I haven't found a Java naming convention for this case.

For example `YELLOW3` or `YELLOW_3`

Comment: Yes, it is advised to do it

Comment: if that number represents an actual value I'd add the underscore, if it just distinguished it from same name constants I'd leave the underscore. - On the other hand you should give you constants names that are easy to understand and somehow enumerated names do not seam to be readable to me...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I didn't know if there is a convention, so I asked here